# How to change ABP default language?

Tags: c#, configuration, localization, settings, aspnetboilerplate

I'm new to using ASP.NET Boilerplate and I want to change the default language to Spanish. I saw that there are some XML files (`localizationSources`) and I've changed the `LocalizationSourceName` in `AppConsts` to point to the `es` XML file, but messages still appear in English.

I've read the ABP documentation, but it is very abstract for me as I'm new to using ABP.

<sub>Note: My English is not very good.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject `ISettingManager` and change the setting:

```
await SettingManager.ChangeSettingForApplicationAsync(LocalizationSettingNames.DefaultLanguage, "en");
```

The value is used as described in [How the Current Language is Determined](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization?searchKey=Default%20language#how-the-current-language-is-determined).

Comment: Where I have to inject that for the change take effect?

Comment: Anywhere. It only needs to be run once per DB.